# Does the electric potential depend on particle velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, electric-fields, potential, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

The energy $E$ of a charged particle with rest mass $m$ and charge $q$, which moves with velocity $v$ in electrostatic field with scalar potential $F$ is
$$E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}+qF$$
Why it is suggested that $F$ does not depend on the velocity of particle? Is there any theory proposing some kind dependence of $F(v)$?

Comment: Is the formula written correctly? I think the total energy will be $$ E = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} -1 )mc^2 + qF$$

Comment: @Knight I believe that your expression is one way of defining *kinetic energy* in the context of special relativity.  The OP's expression is *total energy*.

Comment: @garyp I  intended to write total energy as KE + PE. First expression represents KE and the second one represents  PE.

Answer (score 1):

The only potentials with a dependence on velocity are the [Liénard-Wiechert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) but these are the potentials describing the behavior of a moving charge in classical electromagnetism. These fields imply electromagnetic radiation.